# Recovering ring information from localizations

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

I'm curious if such a statement is true:

> Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unity. Then if $x \in R$ and $x = 0$ in $R_p$ for all primes $p$, where $R_p$ is the localization of $R$ at prime $p$, then $x = 0$ in $R$.

Comment: I agree 100% with the user's comment. Besides, instead of $R$ we can take any $R$-module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes this is true. You can even restrict to maximal ideals. To say that $r\in\ker(R\rightarrow R_\mathfrak{m})$ for a maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$ means that there is some $s\in R\setminus\mathfrak{m}$ with $sr=0$. It follows that $s\in\mathrm{Ann}_R(r)$. If this is true for every maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$ of $R$, then the ideal $\mathrm{Ann}_R(r)$ cannot be contained in any maximal ideal, and therefore must be equal to $R$. So $1\in\mathrm{Ann}_R(r)$, i.e. $0=1\cdot r=r$.